# Different objects selected on different tabs

Tags: rigging, workflow

I am currently rigging a character and every time a make a vertex group for a bone, I want to test to see how it does. However, switching from edit mode from one object, to pose mode on another object takes time, and with a complex rig, this could stack up to lots of wasted time.

I want to have one tab on pose mode of the armature, and one tab on edit mode of the character. However, when I change the selected object, it changes it for all of the tabs. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it won't make the process as fast as you'd like, but if you disable the *Lock Object Modes* option it will speed up a bit when you'll switch from the armature to the object and back to the armature.

[image]

Comment: This is quite helpful, but does this mean that there is no way to do what I wanted without using python of some sort?